# convert list of strings from file to list of integers

Tags: python, string, list, int

I have a large file filled with integers separated by white space and comma. I am trying to read in 1KB at a time and convert it into a list of integers.

This code works fine:

```
with open('test_age.txt', 'r+') as inf:
    with open('test_age_out.txt', 'r+') as outf:
        sorted_list =[]
        a = [x.strip() for x in inf.read(1000).split(',')]
        int_a = map(int, a)
        f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        outf_array = sorted(int_a)
        f.write(str(outf_array))
        f.seek(0)
        #etc...
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, etc...
```

But once I add in a while loop to read the next 1KB:

```
with open('test_age.txt', 'r+') as inf:
    with open('test_age_out.txt', 'r+') as outf:
        sorted_list =[]
        while True:
            a = [x.strip() for x in inf.read(1000).split(',')]
            int_a = map(int, a)
            if not a:
                break
            f = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
            outf_array = sorted(int_a)
            print outf_array
            f.write(str(outf_array))
            f.seek(0)
```

I get the output and a ValueError:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12,
12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18,
19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30,
31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35,
35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40,
40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 42, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 46, 46, 46,
46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 49, 49, 49, 50, 50, 50,
50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 54,
54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58,
59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 61, 62, 62, 62, 62, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64,
64, 64, 65, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 67, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 69, 69, 69, 69, 
69, 69, 69, 70, 70, 70, 70, 71, 71, 72, 72, 73, 74, 74, 74, 75, 76, 76,
76, 76, 77, 77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 79, 79, 79, 79, 81, 81, 81, 81, 82, 82, 
82, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 83, 84, 85, 85, 85, 85, 86, 86, 86, 87, 87, 87,
87, 87, 87, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 89, 89, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 91,
91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 91, 92, 92, 93, 93, 93, 94, 94, 94, 94, 95,  95,
96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 98, 99, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
[2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12,12, 
13, 14, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 20, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 34, 34, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 39, 41, 41, 42, 43,   
44, 44, 46, 46, 47, 48, 49, 49, 49, 49, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 54, 
54, 54, 55, 55, 56, 60, 60, 61, 61, 61, 62, 63, 63, 64, 65, 65, 65, 65, 
66, 66, 67, 68, 68, 68, 70, 70, 73, 73, 73, 74, 74, 75, 75, 75, 77, 77, 
77, 77, 78, 78, 78, 78, 79, 80, 81, 81, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 83, 84, 84, 
85, 85, 85, 85, 86, 87, 88, 90, 91, 91, 91, 92, 93, 93, 93, 94, 95, 97, 
98, 98, 99, 100]
    int_a = map(int, a)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I am not sure why this is happening. If I call print, it seems as if the lists ARE being created and sorted. However the ValueError exists. What gives?

Comment: Well, an empty string isn't a valid base 10 integer, that 's why. You could ask `if a:` *before* you do `int_a = map(int, a)` and/or check for/remove empty strings.

Comment: Maybe you aren't getting a properly-formed string for every 1000 bytes? It'll work properly with single-digit numbers, but if it starts to vary then you'll get bits and pieces left with parts of numbers and commas hanging out by themselves.

Comment: E.g. `a = [int(x) for x in inf.read(1000).split(',') if x.strip().isdigit()]` if you're only working with integers

Comment: Why not do list comprehension, or create a custom function.

`[int(i) if i else 0 for i in a]`
Or:
`def int_(i):    return int(i) if i else 0` and `map(int_, a)`.

This would assume null strings should be 0. Skip them and do the list comprehension for null strings otherwise.

Comment: I have to ask - what are you trying to do with a `TemporaryFile` here?

Comment: @jDo: Yup the file is only integers. Checking the string first would be the way to go. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that simply checking for integers is basically suppressing a failing error. You'd be getting non-integers only if the program is mangling the data. In fact, this program would have to mangle the data - one block could be `1, 2, 3`, which splits fine, and then the next block would have to start with `, `. And that's to say nothing of multi-digit numbers. What if a block ends in the middle of such a number? Instead of, say, `120`, you might have `1` in one block and `20` in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the output of `str.split` with a passed delimiter appearing at the head or tail of a string:

```
>>> ', 3, 5'.split(', ')
['', '3', '5']
```

That empty string is what your program is trying (and failing) to parse as an integer. `''.strip()` doesn't help (and isn't necessary for `int()`, by the way - it automatically ignores leading and trailing whitespace). I recommend reading blocks that are guaranteed to be full and valid, such as lines. If the file is just one big line, you'll have to do some extra work to save the last characters from a line and move them into the next line's processing. Don't forget to process the remaining characters after the loop.

```
line = inf.read(1000)
new += line
current, delimiter, new = line.rpartition(', ')
# process current
# continue loop to add more content
```

If the file can comfortably fit in your system's memory, you could just read the entire file and split it in one go:

```
numbers = map(int, inf.read().split(', '))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and thorough explanation.  The file is WAY to large to fit into memory and I'm actually in the process of learning/implementing External Merge Sort to deal with this particular problem. Thanks again! Cheers.